# Downsample numpy array while preserving distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random, probability

I'm trying to write a function that can randomly sample a `numpy.ndarray` that has floating point numbers while preserving the distribution of the numbers in the array. I have this function for now:

```
import random
from collections import Counter

def sample(A, N):
    population = np.zeros(sum(A))
    counter = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(A):
            for j in range(x):
                    population[counter] = i
                    counter += 1

    sampling = population[np.random.choice(0, len(population), N)]
    return np.histogram(sampling, bins = np.arange(len(A)+1))[0]
```

So I would like the function to work something like this(doesn't include accounting for distribution for this example):

```
a = np.array([1.94, 5.68, 2.77, 7.39, 2.51])
new_a = sample(a,3)

new_a
array([1.94, 2.77, 7.39])
```

However, when I apply the function to an array like this I'm getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-07e3aa976da4> in <module>
----> 1 sample(a, 3)

<ipython-input-63-2d69398e2a22> in sample(A, N)
      3 
      4 def sample(A, N):
----> 5     population = np.zeros(sum(A))
      6     counter = 0
      7     for i, x in enumerate(A):

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Any help on modifying or create a function that would work for this would be really appreciated!

Comment: The argument for `np.zeros` is supposed to be a shape - an integer, or tuple of integers, e.g `np.zeros((2,3))`.  Your `a/A` is an array of floats, so the `sum` will also be a float.

Comment: So how do I fix this? I tried changing the argument to `np.zeros(sum(A.shape))` but it's still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [67]: a = np.array([1.94, 5.68, 2.77, 7.39, 2.51])                                                  
In [68]: np.zeros(sum(a))                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-263779bc977b> in <module>
----> 1 np.zeros(sum(a))

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

sum on the shape does not produce this error:

```
In [69]: np.zeros(sum(a.shape))                                                                        
Out[69]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

But you shouldn't need to use sum:

```
In [70]: a.shape                                                                                       
Out[70]: (5,)
In [71]: np.zeros(a.shape)                                                                             
Out[71]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

In fact if `a` is 2d, and you want a 1d array with the same number of items, you want the product of the shape, not the sum.

But do you want to return an array exactly the same size as `A`? I thought you were trying to downsize.